# Why can't I center an image on a page for printing in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, printing

My application draws charts in a Windows Metafile. Users need to be able to print the charts nicely centered on the page. Quick rundown of printing code:

```
Private Sub PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
     Dim header As Imaging.MetafileHeader = metafile.GetMetafileHeader()
     Dim sz As New SizeF(100 * header.Bounds.Width / header.DpiX, 100 * header.Bounds.Height / header.DpiY)
     Dim p As New PointF((e.PageBounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2, (e.PageBounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2)

     e.Graphics.DrawImage(metafile, p)
End Sub
```

If I print to a PDF, this looks perfect. But if I print to an actual printer it is off center, about 1/8 of an inch down and to the right. I did a quick experiment to see where the PageBounds were by doing

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, e.PageBounds)
```

and the results were the same, slightly off center. On the PDF this draws a rectangle on the very edge of the page. For what its worth, I have tested on a Toshiba e-Studio 3510c and a HP LaserJet 4000 with the same results. Any help is appreciated, this has been plaguing me for weeks.

**Update:**

I ended up using e.PageSettings.PrintableArea, but it looks like e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds gets you the same values as per xpda's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using e.pagebounds for the bounding box, try using e.graphics.VisibleClipBounds. Some printer drivers are a little unreliable with the e.pagebounds, and the visibleclipbounds seems more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem of the printer having different margins on all sides of the page. Instead of positioning your chart relative to the `Bounds`, try to position it relative to the the real border of the page by using these properties:

```
e.PageSettings.PaperSize.Width
e.PageSettings.PaperSize.Height
```

The problem probably doesn't arise with the pdf because you can print on the entire area of the page (i.e. `Bounds.Width` and `Bounds.Height` = 0, which is the same as using the `PaperSize` property).

Answer (score 0):

Below Code:

```
Private Sub PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)

Dim header As Imaging.MetafileHeader = metafile.GetMetafileHeader()
     Dim sz As New SizeF(100 * header.Bounds.Width / header.DpiX, 100 * header.Bounds.Height / header.DpiY)

 Dim LeftMargin, TopMargin As Single

LeftMargin = ((e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Width - sz.width) / 2) + (e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Left / 2)

TopMargin = ((e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Height- sz.Height) / 2) + (e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Top/ 2)


     e.Graphics.DrawImage(metafile, LeftMargin , TopMargin, sz )

End Sub
```